# Map over object values and JSON parse

Tags: javascript

Here's a small function to check if the property starts with `[` or `{` and parse the value from a sting into JSON or an array. Properties might be a string or intiger also.

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash'

export function resolveValues (data) {
  return mapValues(data, item => {
    if (item.match(/^\[/) || item.match(/^\{/)) return JSON.parse(item)
    return item
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first concern is what if `item` just happens to be a string starting with `[` or `{`?

How about instead of testing for `[` and `{`, why not try parsing it? And if it fails, just return as is? This way, you don't need half-hearted checks.

```
export function resolveValues (data) {
  return mapValues(data, item => {
    try{ return JSON.parse(item) }
    catch (e) { return item; };
  })
}
```